# Cakephp 2.x. How can I get translation from specific .po file?

Tags: cakephp, localization

is there a way to get a translation from a .po file with a specific language?

For example I would like to get the English translation from a .po file even though my default cake language is set to Greek.

Of course I could change the default cake language setting to English and then back to Greekbut I don't find this efficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `__()` function uses the `I18n::translate()` function internally. So you could call it directly like this:

```
App::uses('I18n', 'I18n');
$translation = I18n::translate('το κείμενό μου', null, null, 6, null, 'eng');
```

Comment: Good suggestion, although I doubt this will be easier to use than (temporarily) switching the locale to English (that's up to the OP to decide :))